# Windows azure vm refusing connection port 443

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, azure, port-443

I am deploying my sailsjs app using forever in windows azure. And it is taking forever to get my server up and running. Initally it was working fine when it was http but I changed to SSL with self signed certificate and things are not working at all. I tried forever list and it was showing my server was up and running but I can't knock my server at all. I tried to knock the server using curl and it was telling me port 443 connection refused. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearently the issue was I was deploying without a super user access in a linux machine in a port below 1024. If I want to deploy an web app to a port below 1024 I need to have Super user permission. Deploying it with sudo solves the problem.